# Any laser transmission solution for WLAN

Tags: wireless, switching

Dont know if its a good practice or not, but is there any portable cheap hardware for simple laser LOS transmission between two APs?

Comment: Product and/or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term for such equipment is "free space optical".

Unfortunately it's not cheap.